# MS Teams - Don't show notification of specific message in the activity feed

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

## Question

I have a simple [Bot](https://github.com/glconti/jira-bot-teams) for MS Teams developed in C# with the [Bot Builder SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder) 3.15.0.0 targeting .NET framework 4.7.1.

When mentioned, it retrieves the Jira ticket Ids in the message and returns a single reply with a list of Cards, each one displaying a summary of a Jira Issue.

I'd like to know if it's possible to not populate the activity feed when sending the reply with the card attachments as it's not needed for my use case.

## Example

This is how I usually build the reply to a user message

```
var reply = activity.CreateReply();

reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.List;
reply.Attachments = thumbnailCards;

await context.PostAsync(reply);
```

And this is what I tried after reading the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/activity-feed#rest-api-sample

```
var reply = activity.CreateReply();

reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.List;
reply.Attachments = thumbnailCards;
reply.ChannelData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    notification = new
    {
        alert = false
    }
});
await context.PostAsync(reply);
```

I was hoping that setting the `ChannelData` with `notification.alert = false` would just disable the notifications, but it actually doesn't display any message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alert you are getting in the activity feed is simply the "someone replied to your message" alert and is nothing special coming from the bot. This notification in the activity feed cannot be disabled as of now. Other team members won't receive this alert in activity feed unless they are following the same channel.

[Sending notification using Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/activity-feed#rest-api-sample) is designed to work for 1:1 chat.

Comment: Too bad you can't disable it. I hope it will be put in as a feature in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Teams nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams

```
var reply = activity.CreateReply();
reply.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new TeamsChannelData()
                               {
                                    Notification = new NotificationInfo(false)
                               });
```

Source for this package can be found here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/

Comment: I tried your suggestion (didn't know the existence of that package) but, in this case, I don't get any change in behavior at all, the replies are still  displayed in the activity feed

Comment: Are you trying this in 1:1 chat or channel chat?